# Java error with JAXB and Java 1.6

Tags: java, jaxb, version

I'm trying to start the [Octopus Arm Benchmark](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~dprecup/workshops/ICML06/octopus.html) (a reinforcement learning benchmark). I downloaded the [octopus-code-distribution.zip](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~dprecup/workshops/ICML06/Octopus/octopus-code-distribution.zip) and started the octopus-environment.jar with

```
java -jar octopus-environment.jar internal settings.xml
```

and I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType.value()Ljavax/xml/bind/annotation/AccessType;
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getAccessType(ClassInfoImpl.java:339)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:87)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:127)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:49)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:189)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:204)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:327)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:198)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at Main.main(Main.java:41)
```

I already googled the error message and it seems to be a problem with my Java version. I'm using Java 1.6, which somehow causes conflicts with the JAXB library. I think it would work with Java 1.5. But I didn't figure out any workaround yet.

I hope you can help me here. Some background information: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and my Java version is 1.6.0_26.

Comment: Java 1.6 includes the JAXB library. Don't use an external JAXB jar.

Comment: Check out if you downloaded a version for Java 1.7 and not for Java 1.6

Comment: GregS: It is not my code and I didn't want to change it. SHiRKiT: The code is very old (~2006), so I guess it's more likely for Java 1.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JAXB 2.0, `AccessType` is renamed to `XmlAccessType` (`AccessorType` is also renamed to `XmlAccessorType`). Thus, users of early snapshots of JAXB are exposed to this problem. So you have two options:

1. Update the source code so you can use JAXB shipped with Java 6.
2. Override the JAXB implementation with the one used in your environment. The MANIFEST file of the file `octopus-environment.jar` shows the files needed are stored under /lib folder, so you can run

`java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=./lib -jar octopus-environment.jar internal settings.xml`

This leverages the [Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) so you can override the default JAXB shipped in Java 6.

Comment: I don't want to change the source code. Option 2 works very well. Very good explanation. Thank you for your time! :)